# importing common attributes in XSD

Tags: xsd

I have 2 separate XSDs with some common attributes.
I want to create another XSD and put all my common attributes in the separate XSD and import them in the 2 XSDs i have already rather than repeating them or duplicating them in both the XSDs.

Is there any reference for such implementation?

Please let me know if any example or link is there..

Thanks

Comment: please provide some solutions to be accepted